# How do you inherit the template from a parent component in angular 4?

Tags: angular

How would you inherit the template from a parent component in angular 4? Most materials exemplify overriding the parent component like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { EmployeeComponent } from './employee.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-employee-list',
  template: `
    <h1>{{heading}}</h1>
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let employee of employees">
        {{employee.firstName}} {{employee.lastName}} <br>
        {{employee.email}} <br>
        <button (click)="selectEmployee(employee)">Select</button>
      </li>
    </ul>
  `
})
export class EmployeeListComponent extends EmployeeComponent {
  heading = 'Employee List';
}
```

but I want to inherit the template from EmployeeComponent, instead of overriding it with my own custom version. How can this be achieved?

Comment: You can't. Angular is not built to extend components, the typical pattern is to compose them.

Comment: I think you can use parent child interaction https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: What do you want to achieve by doing so? As LakinduGunasekara already suggested can be used for interaction between components or you can also use services.

Comment: @IngoBürk actually it IS built to extend components. You cannot extend parent's template and style, but what you do have is component inheritance (inputs, outputs, host bindings etc.), which is very useful sometimes.

Answer (score 17):

Since you have a child component, you could place it in the parent's directory, and give it an URL that references the parent.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: '../parent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['../parent.component.scss']
})
```

Comment: So obvious yet I didn't think of it. Thanks.

Comment: Agree. Template is not inherited. But if we want to use the same exact template, we can just load that exact template.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to add something to parent template you can just plus it

```
@Component({
  selector: 'child',
  template: require('/path/to/child-template.html') + require('/path/to/parent-template.html')
})
```

(it is using webpack)

Comment: It does not work out of the box with Angular v11 This would need a html-loader to be configured in webpack. 
Unfortunately, Pug (ex Jade) template engine might be a  solution for including partial templates (check tutoria here: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2020/05/angular-templates-pug/l)
However, the Pug loader for Angular doesn't support template inheritance...

Comment: @Const how is it possible to add two templates and get the one original template?