# Angular use template of a base component

Tags: angular, inheritance

I've created a base component for my form element components, which looks like that:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-base-form-element',
  templateUrl: './base-form-element.component.html'
})
export class BaseFormElementComponent {
  @Input() parentForm: FormBuilder
  @Input() error: string
  @Input() fcname: string
  @Input() label: string
...
}
```

and then children-components are initiated with the `extends` keyword to inherit the properties.

However, I would like to inherit also an html template, as all children-components have similar structure, which looks like this:

```
<div class="form-group" [formGroup]="parentForm">
  <label class="form-control-label" for="{{ id }}">{{ label }}</label>
  // here should be child-specific content 
  <span class="invalid-feedback" *ngIf="error">
    {{ error }}
  </span>
</div>
```

How can I implement something like that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you inherit the template from a parent component in angular 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49271582/how-do-you-inherit-the-template-from-a-parent-component-in-angular-4)

Comment: not a duplicate, as the solution simply shows how to use parent's template without any additional markup from the child

Comment: It is a duplicate because the *question* is the same. You do not have to like the answer which currently is "it is not possible" (as stated in some of the answers to the suggested duplicate).

Answer (score 2):

Here's a stackblitz to a possible solution.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-evrvhe?file=src%2Fapp%2Fbase%2Fbase.component.html

Comment: It's not a proper and good solution. It requires putting child's template to an AppComponent template...

Comment: I have updated the stackblitz. I don't know how I've overlooked this solution.